# Starting the game again

Tags: python

I want my program to start the game again when the user enters the letter 'y' on line 55, but for some reason I can't make it to start again. Right now it is "print(switch)" I have also tried "print(str(switch))" and nothing. I want the game to start all over again if the user enters 'y'. What am I doing wrong?

```
import random

win = 0
lose = 0

switch = int(input("Stay or switch? (0-stay/1-switch):")) == 1


n = 0
while n < 100000:

    door_values = [0, 0, 0]
    removable_doors = [0, 1, 2]
    available_doors = [0, 1, 2]

    car_place = random.randint(0, 2)
    door_values[car_place] = 1
    removable_doors.remove(car_place)

    door_chosen = random.randint(0, 2)
    available_doors.remove(door_chosen)
    if door_chosen != car_place:
        removable_doors.remove(door_chosen)

    door_removed_by_host = removable_doors[random.randint(0, len(removable_doors)-1)]
    available_doors.remove(door_removed_by_host)

    if switch:
        assert(len(available_doors) == 1)
        door_chosen = available_doors[0]

    if car_place == door_chosen:
        win += 1
    else:
        lose += 1

    n+=1

print('win=%s'%str(win))
print('lose=%s'%str(lose))
print("This is the number of wins if the user switched", 
round((win)/1000), "%")

print("This is the number of wins if the user didn't switch", 
round((lose)/1000),"%")

answer = input("Play again? (y/n): ")
if answer == 'y':
    print(switch)
elif answer == 'n':
    print("Game Over")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only checking if user enters y or n and not doing anything. Put it in a `while True` loop, like this:

```py
import random
while True:
    win = 0
    lose = 0

    switch = int(input("Stay or switch? (0-stay/1-switch):")) == 1


    n = 0
    while n < 100000:

        door_values = [0, 0, 0]
        removable_doors = [0, 1, 2]
        available_doors = [0, 1, 2]

        car_place = random.randint(0, 2)
        door_values[car_place] = 1
        removable_doors.remove(car_place)

        door_chosen = random.randint(0, 2)
        available_doors.remove(door_chosen)
        if door_chosen != car_place:
            removable_doors.remove(door_chosen)

        door_removed_by_host =removable_doors[random.randint(0,len(removable_doors)-1)]
        available_doors.remove(door_removed_by_host)

        if switch:
            assert(len(available_doors) == 1)
            door_chosen = available_doors[0]

        if car_place == door_chosen:
            win += 1
        else:
            lose += 1

        n+=1

    print('win=%s'%str(win))
    print('lose=%s'%str(lose))
    print("This is the number of wins if the user switched", 
    round((win)/1000), "%")

    print("This is the number of wins if the user didn't switch", 
    round((lose)/1000),"%")

    answer = input("Play again? (y/n): ")
    if answer == 'y':
        print(switch)
    elif answer == 'n':
        print("Game Over")
        break
```

This will break the loop if user enters `n` and continue if entry is `y`.

Answer (score -1):

The `print` function will only print a value on the screen. Instead, you need a mechanism for returning to the `win=0` line. One option would be to wrap your code in a function, and then have the function call itself when the answer == 'y'.

For instance,

```
import random

def run_simulation():
    win = 0
    lose = 0

    switch = int(input("Stay or switch? (0-stay/1-switch):")) == 1

    n = 0
    while n < 100000:

        door_values = [0, 0, 0]
        removable_doors = [0, 1, 2]
        available_doors = [0, 1, 2]

        car_place = random.randint(0, 2)
        door_values[car_place] = 1
        removable_doors.remove(car_place)

        door_chosen = random.randint(0, 2)
        available_doors.remove(door_chosen)
        if door_chosen != car_place:
            removable_doors.remove(door_chosen)

        door_removed_by_host = removable_doors[random.randint(0, len(removable_doors)-1)]
        available_doors.remove(door_removed_by_host)

        if switch:
            assert(len(available_doors) == 1)
            door_chosen = available_doors[0]

        if car_place == door_chosen:
            win += 1
        else:
            lose += 1

        n+=1

    print('win=%s'%str(win))
    print('lose=%s'%str(lose))
    print("This is the number of wins if the user switched", 
    round((win)/1000), "%")

    print("This is the number of wins if the user didn't switch", 
    round((lose)/1000),"%")

    answer = input("Play again? (y/n): ")
    if answer == 'y':
        run_simulation()
    elif answer == 'n':
        print("Game Over")

run_simulation()
```